# Vagrant virtualbox configuration via GUI not SSH

Tags: laravel, configuration, vagrant, virtualbox

I've installed Laravel homestead Vagrant box, and it runs good, no errors, but i decided to work with it not via ssh but virtualbox gui, so i added

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
end
```

to Vagrantfile configuration, and it works but asks for a homestead login, is there a possibility to bypass it?

[image]

Comment: Try enabling auto-login for  the `vagrant` user (which is generally the default one used) like explained in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm/51087#51087).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Vagrant has no option for login without `username` and `password` in `GUI`. In `CLI` it allows login without a password because the default box is created with SSH key based authentication and the default `vagrant` user uses default `SSH` `insecure_private_key` key.

for `auto-login` you can do (below setting for ubuntu 14.04 )

```
sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf
```

and add

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=vagrant
```

Reference :[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin)

you can make script of this and can provision if you don't want this manually in all vagrant VM.